# Unity making a timer

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

So im making a android app in Unity an im trying to make a specific timer so the timer starts as soon as you go the the scene and also I want the numbers to scroll down then stop for a second then scroll again it would look something like this

```
        5
```

### 6

### 00:14:57

```
        8
        9
```

and it would scroll down to the next number ten stop then the next number then stop

how to make a timer in unity with this behavior and look ?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: how to make a timer in unity with that looks nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenity of ways to make a [timer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/351420/simple-timer-1.html), I'm going to assume that that's not the trouble, what you are asking for is an animation that looks nice and works with the data of your timer.

You can have a FSM in the animator to make an animation between three text components so each second them will scroll up, once the upper text is outside the view, ui mask, you put them at the end and then change his text value to the next second and so on in a loop.

Another way to do this is the same I just wrote but using scripting and [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) instead of the animator, I prefer this approaching since I have full control of what are appearing to the user and what are occurring behind in the code.